# Get unique lines based ONLY on 2 Columns

Tags: python, bioinformatics, csv

I have some large (50k line) files formatted like this

```
chr1    35276   35481   NR_026820_exon_1_0_chr1_35277_r 0       -       0.526829        0.473171        54      37      60      54      0       0       205
chr1    35720   36081   NR_026818_exon_2_0_chr1_35721_r 0       -       0.398892        0.601108        73      116     101     71      0       0       361
chr1    35720   36081   NR_026820_exon_2_0_chr1_35721_r 0       -       0.398892        0.601108        73      116     101     71      0       0       361
chr1    69090   70008   NM_001005484_exon_0_0_chr1_69091_f      0       +       0.571895        0.428105        212     218     175     313     0       0       918
chr1    134772  139696  NR_039983_exon_0_0_chr1_134773_r        0       -       0.366775        0.633225        997     1194    1924    809     0       0       4924
chr1    139789  139847  NR_039983_exon_1_0_chr1_139790_r        0       -       0.551724        0.448276        13      12      14      19      0       0       58
chr1    140074  140566  NR_039983_exon_2_0_chr1_140075_r        0       -       0.475610        0.524390        126     144     114     108     0       0       492
chr1    323891  324060  NR_028322_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f        0       +       0.426035        0.573964        37      41      56      35      0       0       169
chr1    323891  324060  NR_028325_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f        0       +       0.426035        0.573964        37      41      56      35      0       0       169
chr1    323891  324060  NR_028327_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f        0       +       0.426035        0.573964        37      41      56      35      0       0       169
chr1    324287  324345  NR_028322_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f        0       +       0.551724        0.448276        19      15      11      13      0       0       58
chr1    324287  324345  NR_028325_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f        0       +       0.551724        0.448276        19      15      11      13      0       0       58
chr1    324287  324345  NR_028327_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f        0       +       0.551724        0.448276        19      15      11      13      0       0       58
chr1    324438  326938  NR_028327_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f        0       +       0.375200        0.624800        400     1013    549     538     0       0       2500
chr1    324438  328581  NR_028322_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f        0       +       0.378228        0.621772        678     1580    996     889     0       0       4143
chr1    324438  328581  NR_028325_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f        0       +       0.378228        0.621772        678     1580    996     889     0       0       4143
```

The 2nd and 3rd columns are a start and end position. I want to delete all rows that have the same start AND end positions (rest of line doesn't matter) and keep only the first time it appears. For example, I'd want to keep lines 14 and 15 in the sample data because even though the start position is the same, the end is not. 15 and 16 have identical start and end, so I'd want to delete 16.I'm trying to do it in Python, but I'm really at a loss for how to handle the two column uniqueness requirement.

Any ideas on the best/easiest way to do this?

Comment: How do you want to keep the good rows?  In memory?  In a new file?

Comment: Basic logic:  Make a set called `seen_start_end`.  For each row make a tuple of columns 2 and 3 called `start_end`.  If `start_end` in `seen_start_end` then `continue` to next row.  Otherwise keep the row and add `start_end` to `seen_start_end`.

Comment: Was going to create a new file

Comment: Are all the lines with both start and end identical as per your example input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the excellent [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library to load and mangle such data:

```
data_string = """
chr1    35276   35481   NR_026820_exon_1_0_chr1_35277_r 0       -       0.526829        0.473171        54      37      60      54      0       0       205
chr1    35720   36081   NR_026818_exon_2_0_chr1_35721_r 0       -       0.398892        0.601108        73      116     101     71      0       0       361
chr1    35720   36081   NR_026820_exon_2_0_chr1_35721_r 0       -       0.398892        0.601108        73      116     101     71      0       0       361
chr1    69090   70008   NM_001005484_exon_0_0_chr1_69091_f      0       +       0.571895        0.428105        212     218     175     313     0       0       918
chr1    134772  139696  NR_039983_exon_0_0_chr1_134773_r        0       -       0.366775        0.633225        997     1194    1924    809     0       0       4924
chr1    139789  139847  NR_039983_exon_1_0_chr1_139790_r        0       -       0.551724        0.448276        13      12      14      19      0       0       58
chr1    140074  140566  NR_039983_exon_2_0_chr1_140075_r        0       -       0.475610        0.524390        126     144     114     108     0       0       492
chr1    323891  324060  NR_028322_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f        0       +       0.426035        0.573964        37      41      56      35      0       0       169
chr1    323891  324060  NR_028325_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f        0       +       0.426035        0.573964        37      41      56      35      0       0       169
chr1    323891  324060  NR_028327_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f        0       +       0.426035        0.573964        37      41      56      35      0       0       169
chr1    324287  324345  NR_028322_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f        0       +       0.551724        0.448276        19      15      11      13      0       0       58
chr1    324287  324345  NR_028325_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f        0       +       0.551724        0.448276        19      15      11      13      0       0       58
chr1    324287  324345  NR_028327_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f        0       +       0.551724        0.448276        19      15      11      13      0       0       58
chr1    324438  326938  NR_028327_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f        0       +       0.375200        0.624800        400     1013    549     538     0       0       2500
chr1    324438  328581  NR_028322_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f        0       +       0.378228        0.621772        678     1580    996     889     0       0       4143
chr1    324438  328581  NR_028325_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f        0       +       0.378228        0.621772        678     1580    996     889     0       0       4143
"""

# this looks suspicously csv-like

import pandas
import StringIO

buf = StringIO.StringIO(data_string)

# this will create a DataFrame object with header: 0, 1, 2, ...
# if you have the file path, you can use that instead of the StringIO buffer
df = pandas.read_csv(buf, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

>>> print df

      0       1       2                                   3   4  5         6   \
0   chr1   35276   35481     NR_026820_exon_1_0_chr1_35277_r   0  -  0.526829   
1   chr1   35720   36081     NR_026818_exon_2_0_chr1_35721_r   0  -  0.398892   
2   chr1   35720   36081     NR_026820_exon_2_0_chr1_35721_r   0  -  0.398892   
3   chr1   69090   70008  NM_001005484_exon_0_0_chr1_69091_f   0  +  0.571895   
4   chr1  134772  139696    NR_039983_exon_0_0_chr1_134773_r   0  -  0.366775   
5   chr1  139789  139847    NR_039983_exon_1_0_chr1_139790_r   0  -  0.551724   
6   chr1  140074  140566    NR_039983_exon_2_0_chr1_140075_r   0  -  0.475610   
7   chr1  323891  324060    NR_028322_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f   0  +  0.426035   
8   chr1  323891  324060    NR_028325_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f   0  +  0.426035   
9   chr1  323891  324060    NR_028327_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f   0  +  0.426035   
10  chr1  324287  324345    NR_028322_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f   0  +  0.551724   
11  chr1  324287  324345    NR_028325_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f   0  +  0.551724   
12  chr1  324287  324345    NR_028327_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f   0  +  0.551724   
13  chr1  324438  326938    NR_028327_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f   0  +  0.375200   
14  chr1  324438  328581    NR_028322_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f   0  +  0.378228   
15  chr1  324438  328581    NR_028325_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f   0  +  0.378228  

# ... more data skipped...
```

Now, it's super easy:

```
# drop duplicates for non-unique sets of values in columns 1, 2 (start, end)
no_dups = df.drop_duplicates([1, 2])

>>> print no_dups
          0       1       2                                   3   4  5         6   \
0   chr1   35276   35481     NR_026820_exon_1_0_chr1_35277_r   0  -  0.526829   
1   chr1   35720   36081     NR_026818_exon_2_0_chr1_35721_r   0  -  0.398892   
3   chr1   69090   70008  NM_001005484_exon_0_0_chr1_69091_f   0  +  0.571895   
4   chr1  134772  139696    NR_039983_exon_0_0_chr1_134773_r   0  -  0.366775   
5   chr1  139789  139847    NR_039983_exon_1_0_chr1_139790_r   0  -  0.551724   
6   chr1  140074  140566    NR_039983_exon_2_0_chr1_140075_r   0  -  0.475610   
7   chr1  323891  324060    NR_028322_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f   0  +  0.426035   
10  chr1  324287  324345    NR_028322_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f   0  +  0.551724   
13  chr1  324438  326938    NR_028327_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f   0  +  0.375200   
14  chr1  324438  328581    NR_028322_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f   0  +  0.378228
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **pandas** to load your file and then delete rows based on the 2 columns as you want like so (a simple example):

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'firstcolumn': ['chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1'],
            'start_position': [35276, 35720, 35720],
            'end_position': [35481, 36081, 36081],
            'A': [4, 4, 31],
            'B': [25, 25, 57]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['firstcolumn', 'start_position','end_position', 'A', 'B'])

df.drop_duplicates(['start_position','end_position']) #drop duplicate rows based on these 2 columns
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that:

```
with open('out_lines.dat', 'w') as out_file:
    with open('in_lines.dat', 'r') as in_file:
        prev_start_end = []
        for line in in_file:
            line_data = line.split()
            if line_data and len(line_data) == 15:
                start = line_data[1]
                end = line_data[2]
                if (start, end) not in prev_start_end:
                    out_file.write(line)
                    prev_start_end.append((start, end))
```

And the output for your input data will be:

```
chr1    35276   35481   NR_026820_exon_1_0_chr1_35277_r 0       -       0.526829        0.473171        54      37      60      54      0       0       205
chr1    35720   36081   NR_026818_exon_2_0_chr1_35721_r 0       -       0.398892        0.601108        73      116     101     71      0       0       361
chr1    69090   70008   NM_001005484_exon_0_0_chr1_69091_f      0       +       0.571895        0.428105        212     218     175     313     0       0       918
chr1    134772  139696  NR_039983_exon_0_0_chr1_134773_r        0       -       0.366775        0.633225        997     1194    1924    809     0       0       4924
chr1    139789  139847  NR_039983_exon_1_0_chr1_139790_r        0       -       0.551724        0.448276        13      12      14      19      0       0       58
chr1    140074  140566  NR_039983_exon_2_0_chr1_140075_r        0       -       0.475610        0.524390        126     144     114     108     0       0       492
chr1    323891  324060  NR_028322_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f        0       +       0.426035        0.573964        37      41      56      35      0       0       169
chr1    324287  324345  NR_028322_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f        0       +       0.551724        0.448276        19      15      11      13      0       0       58
chr1    324438  326938  NR_028327_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f        0       +       0.375200        0.624800        400     1013    549     538     0       0       2500
chr1    324438  328581  NR_028322_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f        0       +       0.378228        0.621772        678     1580    996     889     0       0       4143
```

Comment: I'd make `prev_start_end = set()`

Answer (score 0):

As someone suggested, store your "keys" (start-end fields) in a set, and skip printing the line if the key has previously seen:

```
with open('datafile.tsv','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields=line.split('\t')
        key=tuple(fields[1:3])
        if key in s: continue
        s.add(key)
        print(line)
```

You can redirect python's output to your new file.

Answer (score 0):

```
def unique_positions(filename):
    with open(filename) as lines:
        seen_positions = set()
        for line in lines:
            position = tuple(line.split()[1:3])
            if position not in seen_positions:
                seen_positions.add(position)
                yield line

for line in unique_positions('data.csv):
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the dupes and write to a file you can use groupby, grouping by the two columns and calling next to only get the first line for multiple matches or the only line whichever the case may be,it also stores very little in memory:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("in.csv") as f, open("out.csv", "w") as out:
    for _, v in groupby(f, key=lambda x: x.split()[1:3]):
        out.write(next(v))
```

Output:

```
chr1    35276   35481   NR_026820_exon_1_0_chr1_35277_r 0       -       0.526829        0.473171        54      37      60      54      0       0       205
chr1    35720   36081   NR_026818_exon_2_0_chr1_35721_r 0       -       0.398892        0.601108        73      116     101     71      0       0       361
chr1    69090   70008   NM_001005484_exon_0_0_chr1_69091_f      0       +       0.571895        0.428105        212     218     175     313     0       0       918
chr1    134772  139696  NR_039983_exon_0_0_chr1_134773_r        0       -       0.366775        0.633225        997     1194    1924    809     0       0       4924
chr1    139789  139847  NR_039983_exon_1_0_chr1_139790_r        0       -       0.551724        0.448276        13      12      14      19      0       0       58
chr1    140074  140566  NR_039983_exon_2_0_chr1_140075_r        0       -       0.475610        0.524390        126     144     114     108     0       0       492
chr1    323891  324060  NR_028322_exon_0_0_chr1_323892_f        0       +       0.426035        0.573964        37      41      56      35      0       0       169
chr1    324287  324345  NR_028322_exon_1_0_chr1_324288_f        0       +       0.551724        0.448276        19      15      11      13      0       0       58
chr1    324438  326938  NR_028327_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f        0       +       0.375200        0.624800        400     1013    549     538     0       0       2500
chr1    324438  328581  NR_028322_exon_2_0_chr1_324439_f        0       +       0.378228        0.621772        678     1580    996     889     0       0       4143
```

If you want to change the original file use a tempfile with shutil.move:

```
from itertools import groupby
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move
with open("in.csv") as f, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False) as out:
    for _, v in groupby(f, key=lambda x: x.split()[1:3]):
        out.write(next(v))
move(out.name,"foo.csv")
```